# dotnet cli - specified .runsettings file not used in code coverage run

Tags: c#, .net, testing, code-coverage, cobertura

I have a solution containing two dotnet core 2.1 projects (c#).

1. The first is a console application
2. The seconds is a test project with unit tests

I generate code coverage stats about project 1 when executing tests in project 2 using this command:

```
dotnet test C:\tempDir\SampleApp\Tests\SampleApp.Tests.csproj 
/p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura 
/p:CoverletOutput=C:\tempDir\Coverage\coverage 
/p:settings=CodeCoverage.runsettings --filter Category=Unit --logger trx 
--results-directory C:\tempDir\output
```

You can see here I specify *CodeCoverage.runsettings* as the **settings** parameter - `/p:settings=CodeCoverage.runsettings`.  In my run settings file, I've asked that `Program.cs` and `Startup.cs` are excluded from coverage, but they are still included in the output *coverage.cobertura.xml* file.

Extract from output report below:

```
<classes>
    <class name="SampleApp.Startup" filename="SampleApp\Startup.cs" line-rate="1" branch-rate="0" complexity="2">
      <methods>
        <method name="ConfigureAppConfiguration" signature="(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder)" line-rate="1" branch-rate="0">
          <lines>
            <line number="18" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="19" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="20" hits="1" branch="False" />
          </lines>
        </method>
        <method name="ConfigureLogging" signature="(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration,Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggingBuilder)" line-rate="1" branch-rate="0">
          <lines>
            <line number="23" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="24" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="25" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="26" hits="1" branch="False" />
            <line number="27" hits="1" branch="False" />
          </lines>
        </method>
      </methods>
      <lines>
        <line number="18" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="19" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="20" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="23" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="24" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="25" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="26" hits="1" branch="False" />
        <line number="27" hits="1" branch="False" />
      </lines>
    </class>
</classes>
```

I'm wondering what I've done wrong in my `runsettings` file? (contents of file below)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RunSettings>
    <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>

                        <ModulePaths>
                            <Include>
                                <ModulePath>.*dll$</ModulePath>
                            </Include>
                            <Exclude>
                                <ModulePath>.*microsoft.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*moq.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*polly.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*fluentassertions.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*newtonsoft.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*SampleApp.Tests.*</ModulePath>
                                <ModulePath>.*\\[^\\]*DocumentManagement[^\\]*\.dll</ModulePath>
                            </Exclude>
                        </ModulePaths>

                        <Functions>
                            <Exclude>
                                <Function>.*\.Program\..*</Function>
                                <Function>.*\.Startup\..*</Function>
                                <Function>.*\.SomeOtherClass\..*</Function>
                            </Exclude>
                        </Functions>

                        <Attributes>
                            <Exclude>
                                <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
                                <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                                <Attribute>^System\.Runtime\.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
                                <Attribute>^System\.CodeDom\.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                                <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
                            </Exclude>
                        </Attributes>

                        <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
                        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
                        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
                        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
                        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>

                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>

        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Not sure why this section is still here in this output report, when I specified it being skipped in the *runsettings* file.

NOTE:  I'm trying to avoid littering my code with the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute and I don't want to have to start adding `/p:ExcludeByFile=Program.cs` or `/p:ExcludeByFile=Startup.cs` to my test command in builds, hence using the runsettings file.

Comment: Did you try removing dll from the include section ?

Comment: But I want the dll, just not two classes within the dll...

Comment: Any update? In java and nodejs  is so easy

Answer (score 2):

You cannot exclude classes using runsettings file **by just providing the class name.**

The Function element from run setting matches the full name of a a function / method  like

**YourNamespace.YourClass.Method(parameters);**

There are only below settings which are possible [from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017) :

> Other ways to include or exclude elements ModulePath - matches
> assemblies specified by assembly file path.
>
> **CompanyName** - matches assemblies by the Company attribute.
>
> **PublicKeyToken** - matches signed assemblies by the public key token.
>
> **Source** - matches elements by the path name of the source file in which
> they are defined.
>
> **Attribute** - matches elements to which a particular attribute is
> attached. Specify the full name of the attribute, and include
> "Attribute" at the end of the name.
>
> **Function** - matches procedures, functions, or methods by fully
> qualified name. To match a function name, the regular expression must
> match the fully qualified name of the function, including namespace,
> class name, method name, and parameter list.

What options you have:

**Option 1: Using Starts with OR Using method name**

```xml
<Functions>
  <Exclude>

    <!-- Exclude all methods in SampleApp.Program : -->
    <Function>^SampleApp\.Program\..*</Function>

    <!-- Exclude all methods named Main: -->
    <Function>.*\.Main\(.*</Function>
  </Exclude>
</Functions>
```

In first Function, please note that your namespace with class name is specified and it is starting with ^ character.

In second function element, please note that it is checking method name by checking if a string ends with opening parenthesis '('.

**Option 2: You can use attributes on classes and exclude them from the runsettings file.**

This is similar to `ExcludeFromCodeCoverage` attribute.

Please note the complete [runsettings file at the end of this documentation page.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017#sample-runsettings-file)

Comment: Can you explain what the ^ and (.* characters are doing in the regular expression examples?  The example you've given is for include - do you have an equivalent for exclude?  An example function might be SampleApp.Program.Main (which is the main method of my app) - how could I exclude that?  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: ^ sinigies that the fully qualified name should start with this string.  ( is required if you want to specify exclusion of specific methods.  I hav eupdated exclude example.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me when I use this in the *runsettings* file.  I got it working with the following from the command line (which isn't elegant).  This does work from command line:  `dotnet test C:\tempDir\SampleApp\Tests\SampleApp.Tests.csproj /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura /p:CoverletOutput=C:\tempDir\Coverage\coverage /p:Exclude="[*]*Startup%2c[*]*Program" /p:ExcludeByAttribute="Obsolete%2cExcludeFromCodeCoverage" --filter "Category=Unit"`

Comment: @RobMcCabe, Please add your tip as answer. It works!  `/p:Exclude="[*]*Startup%2c[*]*Program" `